# match all files in current directory

Tags: command-line, powershell, cmd

How do I achieve this in Windows using either Command-prompt or PowerShell?

```
myprog *
```

EDIT: I want to call myprog with each file in the current directory as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to call "myprog.exe" for each file in a directory, assuming that "myprog.exe" does not handle wildcards by itselef, it should be something like that in powershell :

```
dir | % {prog $_.FullName}
```

Edit : taking your comment into account, try this :

```
prog (get-childItem -name)
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I want to run only one instance of myprog with multiple arguments, each argument corresponding to a file in the current directory.

eg: in unix 'myprog *' would expand to 'myprog a.txt g.txt p.txt' ..etc

Answer (score 2):

I wrapped Cédric Rup's solution in a function ea (ExpandAll?). Not as clean as the Unix approach though.

```
function ea ($p="*") { dir $p | foreach { '"{0}" ' -f $_.Name } }

.\Myprog.exe (ea)
.\Myprog.exe (ea *)
.\Myprog.exe (ea *.txt)
```

Comment: In fact, there's no need to protect against space in file names... so a simple get-childItem -name does the trick

Answer (score 1):

In a .CMD or .BAT file:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%f in (*) DO SET params=!params! "%%f"
CALL myprog %params%
```

The `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` and `!variable!` syntax allow you to accumulate the results. (See [this page](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) for explanation and examples.)

Edit: Added quotes around the %%f, and changed the listing to be '*'... see comments below.

Comment: +1 but you should wrap `!params!` in double quotes to protect from spaces in file names

Comment: @Frank: Not at all. You should put `%%f` into quotes. A file list of `""""1.txt" 2.txt" 3.txt" 4.txt" 5.txt` would be a bit strange. ewall: It's enough to use `*` as a wildcard.

Comment: @Johannes I left in the *.* as a simple way of avoiding listing subdirectories... but I should've mentioned the assumption that filenames have . extentions and subfolders don't. Thanks!

Comment: @Johannes: Thanks, thats what I meant, but sometimes things get twisted around in my head

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the following construct in command shell (cmd.exe):

```
for %f IN (*.*) DO echo %f
```

Comment: I want to call myprog with each file in the current directory as an argument.